# How to get the value from toPromise() in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular-services

I am making angular application in which i am making a service call as like,

```
let newValue =  this.dynamicService.getRest(element.optionsUrl,localStorage.getItem('token')).toPromise();
```

and `console.log(newValue)` gives,

```
{"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":[]}
```

Here i need to store the value from the service to the variable `newValue`.

If use `toPromise.then.toPromise().then(function (result) { })` also i am getting the same result.

Kindly help me to store the values of the service with `toPromise()` to the variable `newValue`..

**Edit:**

**Constructor:**

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dynamicService: NgiDynamicFormsService) {
    this.newArray = AppConfig.settings.template.templateFormJSON;
  }
```

**Async getQuestions()**

```
          async  getQuestions() {

            let questions: any = [];

            this.newArray.forEach(element => {
          if (element.elementType === 'textbox') {
            questions.push(new TextboxQuestion(element));
          } else if (element.elementType === 'dropdown') {
                let newValue =  await this.dynamicService.getRest(element.optionsUrl,localStorage.getItem('token')).toPromise();
    element.options = newValue;
    questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element));
            } else if (element.elementType === 'textarea') {
            questions.push(new TextareaQuestion(element));
          } else if (element.elementType === 'checkbox') {
            questions.push(new CheckboxQuestion(element));
          }
            });
return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
```

Here you can see that after getting the `newValue` i need to sends the values in the `newValue` to the `element.options`.. And later on i need to call `questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element));` for this one, i am unable to get the value in `newValue` and so the `questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element))` is giving empty values so after storing the value in `newValue`, i need to call this one, `questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element))`

I need to make this call inside `forEach` function, so if i use **await**, it gives error IDE as,

```
[ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function...
```

Answer (score 3):

To read promise value, use chainable .then operator.

```
let newValue =  this.dynamicService.getRest(element.optionsUrl,localStorage.getItem('token')).toPromise();

newValue.then((value)=>console.log(value));
```

You can also use aynsc/await

```
async func(){
   let newValue =  await this.dynamicService.getRest(element.optionsUrl,localStorage.getItem('token')).toPromise();
}
```

----Promise.all----

```
async  getQuestions() {

    let questions: any = [];
    let questionsPromise: any = [];
    let questionsPromiseResult: any = [];
    this.newArray.forEach(element => {
       if (element.elementType === 'textbox') {
          questions.push(new TextboxQuestion(element));
       } else if (element.elementType === 'dropdown') {
        questionsPromise.push( this.dynamicService.getRest(element.optionsUrl,localStorage.getItem('token')).toPromise());
        questionsPromiseResult.push(element);
      } else if (element.elementType === 'textarea') {
        questions.push(new TextareaQuestion(element));
      } else if (element.elementType === 'checkbox') {
        questions.push(new CheckboxQuestion(element));
      }
    });

    Promise.all(questionsPromise).then(results =>{
       results.forEach(item,index=>{
          let element = this.questionsPromiseResult[index];
          element.options = item;
          questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element));
       });
    });
```

Comment: If i give await, it was giving error because i am making this call inside foreach function.. Kindly see my edited question..

Comment: I have updated my question more detail, there inside foreach many elements were there i just need to do this for ```element.elementType === 'dropdown'``` so inside that i am trying call the service and store the value to ```newValue``` variable.. Using your solution how can i implement that for the ```element.elementType === 'dropdown'``` alone and without going out of foreach.. Please help me to handle this scenario..

Comment: You need to maintain an array for both promises and elements.  Finally you need to merge the result to questions array.

Comment: So what is going to be the variable ```newValue``` in your edited solution..You have given ```questionsPromiseResult.push(newValue);```, but ```newValue``` was not declared with value anywhere..

Comment: Also updated my question ```async getQuestions()``` with correct ending tags with return value.. Kindly check for it also.. Meanwhile i will work with your solution..

Comment: I am getting two errors in ```Promise.all```, 1) [ts] Cannot find name 'item'.
(inside forEach), 2) [ts] Property 'questionsPromiseResult' does not exist on type 'DynamicService'.

Comment: As per your solution i am getting the following in ```console.log(results[0]), ```[{"status":"true","message":"Data is Shown","data":[{"id":6,"name":"Internal"},{"id":7,"name":"External"}]}].... So here i need to store the ```data``` array values from the above to the ```element.options```.

Comment: Atlast i have got it by using ```console.log(results[0]['data']);``` but for this ``` results[0]['data'].forEach(item,index=>{``` i am getting error as, ```[ts] Cannot find name 'item'.``` and also ```[ts] Property 'questionsPromiseResult' does not exist on type 'DynamicService'.``` Also i think there is no need of the foreach because i am getting the value from ```results[0]['data']```.. Just need to store these values to element.options and ```questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(element));```

Answer (score 1):

I give a sample, hope it will gives you understanding of what you want:

in your service file:

```
getTransactions(): Promise<{any}> {
  return this.http.get(`${Api.Url}transaction`).toPromise()
    .then(r => {
      return r;
    }).catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

and in your component.ts where your want to use that service and fetch data:

```
this.transactionService.getTransactions().then(
        r => {
            console.log(r);
        }
    ).catch( e => {
        alert('error fetching data');
    });
```